# Project euler problem 4 don't know why code not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I came up with this code and I cant get the answer although I tried to figure out why

```
First_num = [x for x in range(1000)]
Second_num = 100

def check_palindrome(result):
    result = str(result)
    if result[0:3] == result[6:2:-1]:
        print result


for num in First_num:
    while Second_num < 1000:
        Third_num = num * Second_num
        check_palindrome(Third_num)
        Second_num += 1
```

There was no output

Comment: because `result[0:3]` is never equal to `result[6:2:-1]`

Comment: OH WAIT nevermind just realised my for loop has a huge problem

Answer (score 0):

A few things to comment:

1) **DON'T** use capital case variables, by convention these names are reserved for naming Classes and it's confusing to see this names as a variable. Note that even the SO highlighting marks it in another color. Use some camel-case or snake-case naming such as randomNumber or random_number (these one more common in Python).

2) To check if a value is a palindrome just check that the string is the same as its reverse.

3) I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but your code doesn't have much sense, as x will start by `0` and `0 * second_number` will be always `0`, that is a palindrome, which will result in an infinite loop. Anyway, here you have the fixed version:

```py
first_num = [x for x in range(1000)]
second_num = 100

def check_palindrome(result):
    result = str(result)
    if result == result[-1]:
        print result

for num in first_num:
    while second_num < 1000:
        third_num = num * second_num
        check_palindrome(third_num)
        second_num += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the answer I need by making some tweaks to the code

```
first_num = [x for x in range(1000)]
second_num = 100
palindrome_list = []

def check_palindrome(result):
    result = str(result)
    if result[0:3] == result[6:2:-1]:
        palindrome_list.append(result)

def multiply_list_loop(x, y):
    for num in x:
        z = num * y
        check_palindrome(z)


while second_num < 1000:
    multiply_list_loop(first_num, second_num)
    second_num += 1

print max(palindrome_list)
```

Realised that my for loop wasn't making sense but I will still appreciate any tips